# Graduate schools in set theory

Tags: education

What options for graduate schools are there for an aspiring set theorist?  In the US, the only top 50 schools with active research in set theory seem to be Berkeley and Carnegie Mellon.  Are there any else?

Would it be worth it to go to a foreign university with more active researchers in set theory?

Comment: UIUC is good for set theory. I think UCLA is, too -- they have Itay Neeman.

Comment: This list might be useful (not quite the right area, but might lead you to the right schools): http://grad-schools.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/logic-rankings

Comment: I would caution against placing much weight on US News rankings.

Comment: @AlexBecker I don't think he should be looking at that list for the rankings, but rather as a selection of schools that conduct research in logic.

Comment: UCI http://www.math.uci.edu/research/logic-and-foundations and PSU http://www.math.psu.edu/simpson/Logic.html

Comment: You could come to Israel, HUJI still got Magidor and Shelah... :-)

Comment: More seriously, there is CUNY with Apter and Hamkins.